# How estimate smart contract deployment and transactions price?

Tags: ropsten, price

I can deploy the same smart contract and invoking four transactions on it on Ropsten network.

How can I estimate the price of the exactly same operations but on the Mainnet network?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this without sending any actual transactions.

```
//create a web3 instance
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8546");

//create contract instance, leave address empty if creating new contract
myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface, address, options)

//check gas needed to deploy contract
myContract.deploy({
    data: 'BYTECODE',
    arguments: [123, 'My String']
})
.estimateGas((err, gas) => {
    console.log(gas);
});

//check gas needed to execute method calls of contract
myContract.methods.myMethod(123).estimateGas(function(error, gasAmount){
    ...
});

//to get current gas price of the network
web3.eth.getGasPrice([callback])
```

After this you can multiple the `gasprice` of the network with the `estimated gas` of the `contract deployment` to get the `actual price` to deploy contract and you can do this with every transaction you want to send

Answer (score 1):

When you issue the transactions in Ropsten you'll see their gas usage. After that you need to decide a correct *gas price* for your transaction in the mainnet. You can use for example https://ethgasstation.info/ when deciding on a good gas price.

You can use that same calculator to calculate the actual costs of your transactions once you have decided on the gas price.